# Writing a game: Dynamic attack logic in classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I'm writing an RPG in C#, I have the character classes initialising nicely but I'm struggling with the attack classes.

Each attack will have its unique damage calculation formulas based off of multiple stats and eventually decorators.

Is there a way to dynamically create/append these damage formulas and decorators, or should I create a unique class for each attack that extends a generic attack class?

Here is some Pseudocode for what I'm after:

```
public class Attack
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    List<Decorators> DamageCalc;

    public Attack(string[] data, List<Decorators> decorators)
    {
        Name = data[DataList.Name]; //I'm using constants to keep my indexes readable
        DamageCalc = data[DataList.Damage]; //i.e. strength * 10 + agility
        Decorators = decorators
        ApplyDecorators(Decorators)
    }

    public double DamageCalculation(Character attacker)
    {            
        return DamageCalc; //attacker.Strength * 10 + attacker.Agility
    }

    ...

}
```

Flexibility to add new features and behaviours is of particular interest to me.

Many thanks for your input!

**Edit 1**
Where I to use JSON, would there be any simple way to relate JSON fields to my `Character` class's stat variables or do I need write custom code to interoperate it?

Off hand I can't think of a tidy way to use a JSON field, or any field for that matter, that can dynamically collect information from my `Character` class.

**Edit 2**
Ideally this would allow me to dynamically create all my attacks as instances of a single attack class by taking data from a JSON file, string, XML file or database table.

I changed the code sample on the `DamageCalculation` method.

**Closed**
I the selected answer does provide a solution for my particular problem.  It seems that I really would have to write code to parse formulas and generate the dynamic tool that I'm envisioning.  As such I will see if I can get around this particular problem from a design perspective.

Comment: passing in the settings with a string array on the constructor is fine.  This way you can easily drive the settings from external data sources.

Consider using a more structured format like JSON.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for that.  JSON is something that I'm working up to (I'm still quite new to C#).  Is there any simple way to relate JSON fields to my character class's stat variables or do I need write custom code to interoperate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a base class that contain the signature of your calculations and on the derived classes implement them based on their specialty.

It is a solid, and you can find more about it under the title of "[Strategy Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)"

[image]

Comment: This seems really useful, thank you.  @RobertMoskal suggested I could use data to generate the algorithm.

If I could do so it would allow me to dynamically create instances of the attack class from a table instead of hard coding each and every attack (as with the strategy pattern).

Are my deductions right or did I misunderstand the Strategy Pattern?